# How to exclude some namespaces from xml file while transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I am new to XSL/XML, and I need help with XSL transformation.
In my task I need to transform UBL file to PUF.

For instance, I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">
   <cbc:ID>TOSL108</cbc:ID>
   <cbc:IssueDate>2011-09-22</cbc:IssueDate>
   <cac:InvoicePeriod>
      <cbc:StartDate>2011-08-01</cbc:StartDate>
      <cbc:EndDate>2011-08-31</cbc:EndDate>
   </cac:InvoicePeriod>
   <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
      <cac:Party>
         <cac:PartyName>
            <cbc:Name>Custom Cotter Pins</cbc:Name>
         </cac:PartyName>
      </cac:Party>
   </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
   <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
      <cac:Party>
         <cac:PartyName>
            <cbc:Name>North American Veeblefetzer</cbc:Name>
         </cac:PartyName>
      </cac:Party>
   </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
   <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
      <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="CAD">100.00</cbc:PayableAmount>
   </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
   <cac:InvoiceLine>
      <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="CAD">100.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
      <cac:Item>
         <cbc:Description>Cotter pin, MIL-SPEC</cbc:Description>
      </cac:Item>
   </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

And I need to create file with some pagero namespaces in the root element.
My expected result:

```
<Invoice xmlns="urn:pagero:PageroUniversalFormat:Invoice:1.0"
    xmlns:cac="urn:pagero:CommonAggregateComponents:1.0"
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
    xmlns:puf="urn:pagero:ExtensionComponent:1.0"
    xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
    <cbc:CustomizationID>urn:pagero.com:puf:billing:2.0</cbc:CustomizationID>
    <cbc:ProfileID>urn:pagero.com:puf:billing:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
    <cbc:ID>TOSL108</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2011-09-22</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cac:InvoicePeriod>
        <cbc:StartDate>2011-08-01</cbc:StartDate>
        <cbc:EndDate>2011-08-31</cbc:EndDate>
    </cac:InvoicePeriod>
    <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyName>
                <cbc:Name>Custom Cotter Pins</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyName>
                <cbc:Name>North American Veeblefetzer</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="CAD">100.00</cbc:PayableAmount>
    </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="CAD">100.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Description>Cotter pin, MIL-SPEC</cbc:Description>
        </cac:Item>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

For this I am using the XSL template, like UBLtoPUF.xsl. The problem is, the resulting file looks like this:

```
<Invoice xmlns="urn:pagero:PageroUniversalFormat:Invoice:1.0"
    xmlns:cac="urn:pagero:CommonAggregateComponents:1.0"
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
    xmlns:puf="urn:pagero:ExtensionComponent:1.0"
    xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
    <cbc:CustomizationID>urn:pagero.com:puf:billing:2.0</cbc:CustomizationID>
    <cbc:ProfileID>urn:pagero.com:puf:billing:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
    <cbc:ID xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
        xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2">TOSL108</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:IssueDate xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
        xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2">
        2011-09-22</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cac:InvoicePeriod
        xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
        <cbc:StartDate>2011-08-01</cbc:StartDate>
        <cbc:EndDate>2011-08-31</cbc:EndDate>
    </cac:InvoicePeriod>
    <cac:AccountingSupplierParty
        xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyName>
                <cbc:Name>Custom Cotter Pins</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:AccountingCustomerParty
        xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyName>
                <cbc:Name>North American Veeblefetzer</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal
        xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="CAD">100.00</cbc:PayableAmount>
    </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cac:InvoiceLine
        xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
        <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="CAD">100.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Description>Cotter pin, MIL-SPEC</cbc:Description>
        </cac:Item>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

There is a `xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"` namespaces which appeared on the `<Invoice>` child nodes.
These namespaces are ONLY propagating through in direct `/Invoice` child nodes, but no other children of children etc.
So I am doing everything right (somehow) on all the children's children, etc., but NOT on direct children of `/Invoice`.

There is a template which I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
    xmlns:puf="urn:pagero:ExtensionComponent:1.0"
    xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
    xmlns="urn:pagero:PageroUniversalFormat:Invoice:1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Invoice xmlns:cac="urn:pagero:CommonAggregateComponents:1.0"
            xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
            xmlns:puf="urn:pagero:ExtensionComponent:1.0"
            xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
            <cbc:CustomizationID>urn:pagero.com:puf:billing:2.0</cbc:CustomizationID>
            <cbc:ProfileID>urn:pagero.com:puf:billing:1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="//*[local-name() = 'Invoice']/*[not(namespace-uri() = 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2')]" />
        </Invoice>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template
        match="//*[local-name() = 'Invoice']/*[namespace-uri() = 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2']">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="">
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="node()/*[not(namespace-uri() = 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2')]" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Suppress the UBLVersionID element -->
    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name() = 'UBLVersionID']" />

    <!-- Copy attributes as-is, except for the namespace attributes -->
    <xsl:template
        match="@*[not(namespace-uri() = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')]
                       [not(namespace-uri() = 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2')]
                       [not(namespace-uri() = 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2')]
                       [not(namespace-uri() = 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2')]
                       [not(namespace-uri() = 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2')]">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Copy elements as-is -->
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="@*[not(namespace-uri() = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')]
                       [not(namespace-uri() = 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2')]
                       [not(namespace-uri() = 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2')]
                       [not(namespace-uri() = 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2')]
                       [not(namespace-uri() = 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2')]" />
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried to change `<xsl:template match="node()">` but it does not help. I did not find any questions how to exclude namespaces using template.
Please help me how can I change my template to get rid of this namespaces of `<Invoice>` child elements?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact expected result.

Comment: Also I see no `UBLVersionID` element  in the input?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I've edited, the expected result is the second xml block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, you want to do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:cac="urn:pagero:CommonAggregateComponents:1.0"
xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
xmlns:puf="urn:pagero:ExtensionComponent:1.0"
xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
           
xmlns:inv="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
xmlns:cac0="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
exclude-result-prefixes="inv cac0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*"> 
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="/inv:Invoice"> 
    <Invoice xmlns="urn:pagero:PageroUniversalFormat:Invoice:1.0">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Invoice>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="cac0:*"> 
    <xsl:element name="cac:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have left out this part:

```
   <!-- Suppress the UBLVersionID element -->
    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name() = 'UBLVersionID']" />
```

because I see no `UBLVersionID` element in the input. It is bad practice to rely solely on the local name of an element - esp. in a heavily namespaced XML such as your input. You should use a fully qualified name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the rules for namespaces on constructed elements.

First remember that the data model is all about *in-scope* namespaces, not about namespace declarations. An element has a set of namespace bindings (prefix-uri mappings) that are in scope for that element; it doesn't matter whether the namespace was declared on that element or on some ancestor. So declaring a namespace redundantly on the `Invoice` element in your stylesheet, when it's already declared on the `xsl:stylesheet` element, is pointless.

When the time comes to serialize a result tree, the serializer will generate namespace declarations so that all the *in-scope* namespaces (and only the *in-scope* namespaces) on elements in the result tree are declared, eliminating redundant declarations.

There are three ways of creating elements, and they have different rules for what in-scope namespace bindings will be present on the new element:

- A literal result element (like `<Invoice>`) copies all the in-scope namespace bindings from the stylesheet to the result tree, other than any that are excluded by virtue of `exclude-result-prefixes`. It also adds any namespaces that might be needed for the names of the element's attributes.
- An xsl:element instruction creates the new element with the minimum set of in-scope namespaces needed for the names of the element and its attributes
- An xsl:copy or xsl:copy-of instruction copies the in-scope namespace bindings from the source element that you are copying.

So if you look at the namespaces you are getting on the `cbc:ID` element in your result document (for example), it looks to me as if this element was produced using an `xsl:copy` instruction so you need to understand that `xsl:copy` copies the in-scope namespaces of the source tree element being copied.

XSLT 2.0 has an attribute `<xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">`, but in 1.0, if you want to drop namespace bindings, you have to switch from `xsl:copy` to `xsl:element`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's more clear to me now!